# Improving the visualization of my bar chart (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

how should I improve the visualization of my bar chart (as attached), I would like to label my x-axis with specific time points (0, 0.5, 8, 24, 48) instead of the default value as shown in the image. In the image, the bars are packed and quite close to each other at 0 and 0.5 time point, also the bars' width are so narrowed and thin to the extent that they are hard to be differentiated between different factors. My script is as per below, thanks in advance! p.s. I'm a beginner in R

```
ggplot(data=Exp1, mapping = aes(x = time, y = npq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = growth_condition), position = "dodge") +
  labs(title= "NPQ", x= "Time (hours)",  y="NPQ", fill= "Growth condition")
```

[image]

Comment: If you change `aes(x = time, y = npq)` to `aes(x = factor(time), y = npq)`, does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Jared, appreciate your reply, that's amazing! The bar chart looks much more better and is exactly the one I wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: If the x-axis variable is numeric and continuous, you should probably consider using points or lines, rather than bars.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, will definitely consider that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"aes(x = time, y = npq)" to "aes(x = factor(time), y = npq)"

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify what exactly you did with this code rather than simply the code by itself. As it is written, it may not be easy to understand, especially for people new to R.